# nfs mounting directory which mounted another host

Tags: linux, mount, nfs

I have 3 PCs(host1, host2, host3).

host1 and host2 are connected.

host2 and host3 are connected.

host1 is mounted on host2.

So host2 can access shared directory of host1.

What I want to do is sharing this directory to host3.

I don't have enough information about this, so I wonder is it possible.

Can anyone provide solution for this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Search for `re export nfs share`. Yes, it can be done, but you may have problems. You would be better mounting directly - set host2 to route traffic - rather that re export.